# How to set ARIMA parameters p,q,d or should I go for Auto ARIMA?

Tags: time-series, arima, pmdarima

I have tried to set ARIMA parameters p,q,d for time series which was not stationary but predictions were poor, I believe it's because of the values I chose for p,q,d .If could anybody explain how to set these parameters or should I go for Auto ARIMA?

Comment: The answer is open since to choose the parameters (p,d,q) you have to check a unit root test like checking your correlogram to assign "manually" the values of p,d,q. The other alternative is to use the 'auto.arima' function. Please see a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/11570343).

Comment: You can see [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/104818/249601).